# IOS 9 Keep a TCP connection open over lte when device connect to wifi

Tags: ios, networking, tcp, wifi, lte

Hi I have few questions regarding the IOS connectivity .
I am using SCNetworkReachabilityFlags to detect any change in the connectivity on IOS.

If bind my socket over lte and few minutes after a connection to WIFI is established, Will my socket be able to keep sending/receiving data over LTE or will IOS close my socket ?

Answers:

I will answer my own question:
Even on WIFI the LTE connection is not closed, I had an issue in my test.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question: Even on WIFI the LTE connection is not closed, I had an issue in my test.